How can I get my local server be accessed from the public domain I've registered?
I have a domain I've already registered "example.com". I've been using digital ocean cloud server to manage the apps after applying the digital ocean nameservers in my registrar.
Now I have my own physical server with a static IP that already can be accessed from the internet via IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XX. My worry is no how do I connect my public domain example.com to my server since I do not have any DNS entries? I've tried to put my public IP as the NDS entry but is not accepting.

I solved it by adding the domain to cloudflare(dash.cloudflare.com). I entered the nameservers provided by cloudflare at my domain registrar ie;

armfazh.ns.cloudflare.com
gene.ns.cloudflare.com

After updating the nameservers at my domain register, I added my static IP as a DNS entry in cloudflare ie
DNS type: A
DNS name: example.com
Content: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (My static public IP)
